# Rstudio: Некорректно отображается кириллица в скрипте

Tags: кодировка, шрифты, r, rstudio

Я скачал скрипт, содержащий кириллицу. При открытии в Rstudio вместо русских слов непонятные символы. То же происходит и при построении графиков. Если же я изменяю скрипт сам, то никаких проблем с кириллицей нет. Проблема в том, что мне необходимо понять именно что написано в скачанном скрипте. Как это сделать?

```
# Р±СѓРґРµС‚ РІРѕР·РІСЂР°С‰Р°С‚СЊ РѕС‚РЅРѕСЃРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅС‹Рµ С‡Р°СЃС‚РѕС‚С‹).
hist(data, plot = TRUE, freq = TRUE, col = "darkviolet", ylab = "Р§Р°СЃС‚РѕС‚Р°", xlab = "РРЅС‚РµСЂРІР°Р»С‹")
```

Comment: Вангую, что кодировка файла cp1251, а в IDE кодировка редактора utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Откройте файл в Rstudio. Нажми на вкладку File (верхний левый угол),выбери "Reopen with encoding". Скорее всего, это UTF-8.

Чтобы сохранить файл и не переоткрывать его каждый раз выберите в File "save with encoding" и CP1251. Это важно делать ПОСЛЕ переоткрытия файла с необходимой кодировкой.